# How app engine perform caching using google cloud endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an android application using google app engine, cloud endpoints, datastore and objectify. I want do caching of application's  data so that request on the server comes only when there is a change in the application's data.
There is field name **etag** associated with each response from app engine server which can be use for the cache. But i don't know how to do that.
I think there is built in caching but I am not sure.

**Question**

Does app engine provide  built-in caching? if yes then how? if no then how can I acheive that using endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable caching in Objectify. If you do that all data will be stored in the App Engine MemCache. That would improve your performance a lot.

Comment: Question was related to endpoint caching during network transport not about Objectify caching. Thanks for your reply!